# Three js: How to get normal of rotated plane

Tags: three.js, plane

I am trying to get normal of rotated plane. My solution is to **copy the updated plane** then **get normals**.
It is working when I rotate by only 1 angle, but not works in rotating by 2 or 3 angles. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sea421/nud7yp8v/33/)

Green one is copied plane, purple one rotated plane.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pAd5.png)

How to solve this? Please help me

My copy function:

```
 function copyPlane() {
    let copyPlaneGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3, 3);
    copyPlaneGeom.rotateX(plane.rotation.x);
    copyPlaneGeom.rotateY(plane.rotation.y);
    copyPlaneGeom.rotateZ(plane.rotation.z);
    let copyPlane = new THREE.Mesh(copyPlaneGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00}));
        scene.add(copyPlane)
    
    let normals = copyPlane.geometry.faces[0].normal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with that approach, you'll always get a vector of `0, 0, 1` because a plane's face normal is always `(0, 0, 1) * objectRotation`.

Instead, try starting with a Vector3 of `0, 0, 1`, and then apply the object's rotation to it:

```js
var originalNormal = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);

// Get the mesh rotation
var objRotation = plane.rotation;

// Apply mesh rotation to vector
originalNormal.applyEuler(objRotation);
```

now you have a Vector3 with the updated wold normal, instead of the local normal! Read about [`.applyEuler()` here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.applyEuler).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I want. You saved my day :)